# $\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ being isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{mn}$

Tags: matrices, group-theory, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I am reading Tu's book titled "Introduction to Manifolds". In Chapter 2, paragraph 5.3, example 5.15 states that

> ...Since $\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{m n}$, we give it the topology of $\mathbb{R}^{m n}$...

I have a few questions about this statement:

1. If we have to say that $\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{m n}$, that means that these two spaces are different? How are they different? What is the first space and what is the second?
2. we give the topology of $\mathbb{R}^{m n}$ to what? To $\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$? And if so, why are we allowed to give the topology of some space to another, given that they are isomorphic?
3. How is all that useful for what is next, i.e. defining the general linear group of $n\times n$ matrices with real entries?

Any help will be appreciated...

Comment: If two spaces are isomorphic then they are the same up to labelling.

Comment: Hi @AlvinL and thanks for your comment. What does "up to labelling" mean exactly?

Comment: I would take ${\bf R}^{m\times n}$ to mean $m\times n$ matrices with real entries, ${\bf R}^{mn}$ to mean ordered $mn$-tuples with real entries. Different, but isomorphic as vector spaces, inner product spaces, metric spaces,....

Comment: It means the structure is the same, but you might denote elements in different ways. You should also specify what kind of isomorphism you are talking about.

Comment: @AlvinL not really sure about the kind of isomorphism. But thanks, I think now I kind of get it.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson thank you as well for your comment

Comment: The point is that finite-dimensional $\mathbb R$-vector spaces can be given a "canonical" topology by identifying it with $\mathbb R^N$ for some $N$, via choosing a basis.

Comment: What is $\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ supposed to mean? Matrices? What a weird, non-standard and confusing notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q1:

Both $\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ and $\mathbb{R}^{m n}$ are vector spaces over the ground field $\mathbb R$ with dimensio $m \cdot n$. However, the elements of $\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ are $(m \times n)$-matrices $A = (a_{ij})$ and the elements of $\mathbb{R}^{m n}$ are tupels $(x_1,\ldots, x_{mn})$. The two vector spaces are isomorphic, but not identical. An isomorphism is given by writing down the rows of a matrix one after the other, that is
$$\phi : \mathbb{R}^{m\times n} \to \mathbb{R}^{m n}, \phi((a_{ij}) = (a_{11},\ldots,a_{1n},a_{21}, \ldots, a_{2n}, \ldots, a_{m1},\ldots,a_{mn}) .$$

Note that there are many other isomorphisms. For example we can write down the columns of a matrix one after the other.

Euclidean spaces $\mathbb R^k$ have a standard topology induced by the Euclidean norm $\lVert (x_1,\ldots,x_k) \rVert = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^k x_i^2}$.

We can now give $\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ the unique topology making $\phi$ a homeomorphism. But doesn't this topology depend on the **choice** of a linear isomorphism $\phi$ between $\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ and $\mathbb{R}^{m n}$? It is an easy exercise to show that this is not the case: For all isomorphisms $\phi : \mathbb{R}^{m\times n} \to \mathbb{R}^{m n}$ we get the same topology. By the way, this topology is induced on the Euclidean matrix norm $\lVert (a_{ij}) \rVert = \sqrt{\sum_{i,j} a_{ij}^2}$.

Q2:

This has been already answered. Generally speaking, if we have a bijection $\beta : S \to X$ from a set $S$ to a topological space $X$, we can give $S$ the unique topology making $\beta$ a homeomorphism. Explicitly, if $\mathcal T_X$ is the topology of $X$, then we give $S$ the topology $\mathcal T_S  = \beta^{-1}(\mathcal T_X) = \{ \beta^{-1}(U) \mid U \in \mathcal T_X \}$.

Q3:

The general linear group $\operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb R)$ is a certain subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. Since we endowed $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ with a topology, $\operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb R)$ becomes a topological space (with the subspace topology inherited from $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$). In fact it is an *open subspace* of $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and therefore a manifold.